# How to fold clothes to save packing space for travel?

Tags: travel, packaging

How to pack your clothes in an efficient way to have enough space for other clothings and stuffs to fit into your luggage or carry on?

I learned some ways to [pack your shirts in a military roll](http://lifehacker.com/perfectly-pack-t-shirts-with-the-six-inch-military-roll-1416997152) and is effectively provide enough space for my other clothes to fit into.

How to fold pants, sweaters, long sleeves, and polo that is wrinkle-free? Where to place your belts, socks, underwears, bathroom stuffs, etc?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen answers to this many times before but the most efficient way is to use vacuum plastic bags where you put your clothes in a plastic bag and then suck the air out. This is theoretically the most efficient space saving method.

[This article has a cheap way of performing this function.](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Vacuum-Packing-aka-the-Poor-Mans-Spacebag/) Which is just putting your clothes/fabrics in a plastic bag (that has no holes), close the bag and slide in a hose of any vacuum and let it vacuum all the air out it can. Once it stops shrinking, remove the hose from the bag and tie the bag shut.

Answer (score 0):

The roll you are describing is sometimes referred to as a ranger roll, (see [google search for ranger roll](http://google.com/search?q=ranger+roll) with answers like [this one](http://coed.com/2014/05/01/8-ways-packing-like-a-us-army-ranger-will-help-you-kill-baggage-fees/)) and this can be applied to most kind of clothings. To do it with t-shirts, long sleeves, polo and sweaters, should be easy to do. Just fold the sleeves down along the garment, and roll as usual.

The pants is a little more tricky, but the trick is to make the fold at the waist line, and to keep the flies/fly-front/zip open and kept slightly apart to keep these from bulking up. Also remember to turn the pants around so that the final pocket to wrap around the bundle is the back of the pants, and not the front. After this preparation, you just roll and wrap like normal.

Socks can also be ranger rolled, but I prefer to simply put two socks together and wrap one around the other. It still makes for a neat little bundle.

For other miscellaneous items, put them inbetween the others, possibly in bags or boxes if that is suitable. But at least your clothes should now be in nice little rolls and bundles. Easily accessible and packable.